# Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am using sharepoint designer.Just beside terms and Conditions Check box I need to put a hyperlink Which will open up a web page with all terms and conditions. How can I do that in sharepoint designer.

Many thanks

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous, could you specify? You want to insert a hyperlink somewhere on a page? Did you try Insert > Hyperlink? Please give some more information and the version of Sharepoint/Sharepoint Designer you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the page in Sharepoint Designer
2. At the appropriate location, put in a hyperlink like this:

<A HREF="termsandconditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a>

For more information, see http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp

Answer (score 1):

<
input type="CHECKBOX" id="switchBox" name="switchBox" runat="server" /> 
I agree and accept the 
 
Terms & Conditions

Comment: I have terms and conditions checkbox. All the validations are being done on it. Which is fantastic.  Beside the terms and conditions check box I want to place a hyperlink, which will show up the document containing terms and conditions. I am using Jquery in webdesigner so I need to use javascript for this requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Shared%20Documents/Terms%20and%20Conditions%20of%20Waiting%20Pool.doc">Read Terms &amp; Conditions
                            </asp:HyperLink></td>
```

It worked..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Specify your code bz to add a hyper link with check box..
Or a simple method I don't understand ur query
 terms & conditions